# Custom json in Drupal 7

Tags: json, drupal-7

I am a beginner in Drupal 7 and I am trying to build a custom JSON by using the taxonomy terms. I have implemented the taxonomy terms with parent child relationship and I want to build the same for json. For example, I have a term term Activism which a parent for several other term. Thus, I am looking for a JSON something like this.

```
{
 "name":"Terms",
 "children" : [
{
  "name":"Activism",
  "children" : [{
    "name" : "American Civil Liberties Union (ACLU)",
    "size" : "1"
  },
   {
    "name" : "Bertrand Russell",
    "size" : "1"
   }]
 }]
}
```

Can anyone help how to proceed with it. It seems the JSON data document does not provide such relational structuring.

Comment: What do you mean by "proceed with it"? You have your parent & child terms in your JSON.

Comment: I want to create a JSON structure as specified above in drupal 7. I am using taxonomy terms which has been created accordingly as parent-child. How can I create JSON out of those taxonomy terms in drupal 7.